# Can not log netcat output from within script in a cron job

Tags: unix, cron, netcat

I have a script:
`/home/blah/test.sh`
that contains the lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:
netcat -v -w 5 169.254.123.123 xx >> /home/blah/output.txt
```

Where xx is the port number.

This script runs no problem from the command line, and the script runs when invoked via cronjob, but the output of `netcat` is empty except for the "success" message output by the verbose flag to `netcat`.

I have compared PATH variables and I have also explicitly tried `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the crontab file before the cron entry. I have also obtained the `env` details using `* * * * * env > /home/blah/env.blah` and tried:

```
env - `cat /home/blah/env.blah` /home/blah/test.sh
```

This works, but I can not get the output from netcat to work within cronjob. A `which netcat` returns `/bin/netcat` so I've also tried replaceding `netcat` in the script with `/bin/netcat` and that also does not work.

I have tried it in crontab for user blah and for root -> for root both using `sudo crontab -e` and alternatively editing `/etc/crontab` (explicitly specifing the username as required). crontab entries tried:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/blah/test.sh>>/home/blah/log.out 2>>/home/blah/log.err
*/5 * * * * /home/blah/test.sh
*/5 * * * * /home/blah/test.sh>>/home/blah/log.out >>/home/blah/log.err 2>&1
```

And some others

Using Linux Mint 17.1 (Rebecca).

Any thoughts are appreciated.

**Solution** `-d` flag is needed for netcat to run called from a cron job.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225502/discussion-on-question-by-argh-bargle-can-not-log-netcat-output-from-within-scri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer** (details are in the comment string to the original post):
The problem laid in the difference of invoking `netcat` from the shell vs. invoking `netcat` from a cronjob. Within cron there is not a shell instance, the solution to this is by invoking the `-d` option which suppresses `netcat`'s need for a shell.

Thanks to all the commenters for their help!